# Spring asyncRestTemplate for SOAP Services

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a soap service using Spring's AsyncRestTemplate.
I know that AsyncRestTemplate supports only rest call and spring-ws is there if we need to make soap calls. But Spring-ws doesn't support Async calls and uses JDK's HttpURLConnection class for doing http call and I wanted to make async soap webservices call. 
Below is my code for creating the soapenvelop using JDKs saaj api.

```
public SOAPEnvelope createSoapEnvelope(Employee obj){
        MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    try {
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

        QName bodyName = new QName(Constants.SERVICE_NAMESPACE);
        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        // Marshal the Object to a Document
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(obj, document);
        body.addDocument(document);
        return envelope;
    }catch (SOAPException | JAXBException  | ParserConfigurationException e){
        LOGGER.error("Unable to marshal ",e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I set this soap envelop in HttpEntity to make the call though rest template like below

```
MultiValueMap headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,"text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING,"gzip,deflate");
    headers.set("SOAPAction", Constants.SOAP_ACTION);
    HttpEntity<SOAPEnvelope> soapEntity = new HttpEntity<>(soapEnvelope,headers);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<SOAPEnvelope>> future=
            restTemplate.postForEntity(url,
   ,soapEntity,SOAPEnvelope.class);
```

After doing this I get exception `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl] and content type [text/xml;charset=UTF-8]`

I understood from this exception that Spring's HttpMessageConverters are not able to marshal SoapEnvelop and that's why this client is not able to submit the request.

I need help in writing custom message converter and registering it with rest template. All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks